# Processing files as well as directories

Tags: bash

I am using the `find` command, to which I am passing an array composed of directory paths (stored in `fdir`).  The matches which I then pass to head.

```
for dpa in "$@"; do
  [[ ! -d $dpa || -f $arg ]] && continue
  [[ ${tag[mo:$dpa]} ]] && continue
  fdir+=("$dpa")
  tag[mo:$dpa]=1
done

hn=21 
sufx=( -name *.sh -o -name *.c )
mxdpt=( -maxdepth 3 )
find "${fdir[@]}" -type f "${sufx[@]}" "${mxdpt[@]}" \
  -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
```

I am encountering a problem when some elements of `fdir` are files rather than directories.  Let an element of `fdir` be `/home/flora/com.org`, the `find` command would fail because of `sufx`.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. What should handle files? If it's `find`, it's already handling files given its `-type f` arguments

Comment: If I pass `/home/flora/type.sh` the file is not included in `fdir` because it is not a directory.  I want to be able to pass filenames as well as directory names in the argument list.  If I pass a filename on `fdir`, I want the file to get processed correctly and passed to the `head` command.

Comment: Try removing the `[[ ! -d $dpa ]] && continue` line in your for loop. Its purpose is to skip files

Comment: I still want to perform the checks in case there are invalid filenames or invalid dirnames.

Comment: What do you consider an invalid name? One that doesn't exist? `[[ -d $dpa || -f $dpa ]] || continue`

Comment: One that does not exist, else bash will complain.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the first line in the for loop to

```
[[ ! -e $dpa ]] || continue
if [[ -f $dpa ]]; then
  head $dpa
  continue
fi
```

Comment: The problem I am encountering in the necessity of excluding the file types in `sufx` when a file rather than a directory is being passed as a function argument.

Comment: You could call find instead of head in the if statement
`find "${dpa}" -type f "${sufx[@]}" -exec head -v -n 21 '{}' +`

Comment: I am thinking on passing each file or directory, one at a time.  And for files remove the `"${sufx[@]}"`.